# Secure Login with socket

Tags: php, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to create a secure login program by using sockets. Here's the code I wrote:

```
<?php

$myusername=$_POST["username"];
$mypassword=$_POST["password"];
$host="localhost";
$port=80;
$timeout=60;
$target="/admin_area.php";
if($myusername=="admin" && $mypassword=="passwd")

{
  if (!$sock=fsockopen("ssl://".$host,$port,$errnum,$errstr,$timeout))

  {
    die ("Could not open socket: [$errnum] $errstr");
  }

  else
  {
    $posted_vars=array("username"=>$myusername,
                       "password"=>$mypassword);
    $body="";
    foreach ($posted_vars as $parameter=>$value)

    {
      $body.="&".$parameter."=".$value;
    }
    $headers="POST ".$target." HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
    $headers.="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded \r\n";
    $headers.="Content-Length: ".strlen($body)." \r\n";
    $headers.="Connection: Keep-Alive \r\n";
    $headers.="Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($myusername.":".$mypassword)." \r\n\r\n";
    fputs ($sock,$headers.$body);
    $data="";
    while (!feof ($sock))

    {
      $data.=fgets($sock,3000);
    }
    list($res_head,$res_body)=explode("\r\n\r\n",$data);
    echo $res_body;
  }
}

else
  
{
  echo "Login not happened successfully";
}

?>
```

When I run it, the following warnings are returned:

> Warning: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol in C:\wamp\www\log_in.php on line 12
>
> Warning: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\wamp\www\log_in.php on line 12
>
> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://localhost:80 (Unknown error) in C:\wamp\www\log_in.php on line 12
>
> Could not open socket: [0]

The issue is that this code works correctly if I remove the instruction for using the SSL protocol in the `fsockopen()` function, but I would need to implement a secure HTTP connection.

I would be very grateful to anybody who can tell me where I am wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: should you not use $port=443;

Comment: I've already tried this option but in that way it returns another error: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://localhost:443

Comment: And you are sure localhost https is correctly up and running?

Comment: do you mean the OpenSSL support? If you are referring to that, yes, it is working.

Comment: As far as I can see, there's nothing wrong with your script. There has to be something wrong with the SSL-setup.

Comment: Everything concerning SSL seems to be enabled. Anyway thank you for your response.

Comment: Well, you could try to study the error-log from the server you are trying to connect to. Guess it has more detailed information about what is failing.

Comment: You must have openssl extension to use HTTPS/SSL with php.

Comment: You must use the proper port for SSL - so that's 443.  As was mentioned above, you tried that and got a different error.  You should update your code to say you are using 443, and then confirm that surfing to https://localhost does not generate any error for you.  Then, perhaps participants can help you further. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making some changes here to specify exactly what you need.

```
if (!$sock=fsockopen("ssl://".$host,$port,$errnum,$errstr,$timeout))
```

SSL Does not use port 80 which will be the default, so specify the $port as 443.

It has been known to cause problems on some systems where the version of SSL in use is not specified, and relies on php to try to detect it. I would suggest trying either

```
if (!$sock=fsockopen("sslv2://".$host,443,$errnum,$errstr,$timeout))
```

or

```
if (!$sock=fsockopen("sslv3://".$host,443,$errnum,$errstr,$timeout))
```

Depending if your server is using SSLv2 or SSLv3.

This removes any ambiguity and clearly instructs the server how to proceed